# Running an ssh connection as a daemon

Tags: python, ssh, daemon, gerrit, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to monitor `gerrit` events through an `ssh` command. The command is as follows.

```
ssh -p 29418 review.example.com gerrit stream-events
```

I need to monitor various such `gerrit` instances running on different `ports` and perform further analysis on the events received from these `gerrit` instances. I want to do it through code using `python`. I considered running these various `ssh` connections as multiple processes, for this I used the `multiprocessing` `python` package an tried to use the `daemon` attribute to run the process as a `daemon`. Below is a snippet of my code.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class MyProcess(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, target, args):
        mp.Process.__init__(self, target=target, args=args)

while True:
    running = get_runnig_instances() #get all the running gerrit instances
    for instance in running:
        port_num = instance.port
        url = instance.ip
        proc = MyProcess(target=client_setup, args=(url,port_num,)) #client_setup(url,port_num) is a function that runs the command for the ssh connection to stream gerrit events
        proc.daemon = True
        proc.start()
        proc.join()
```

This did not work as after running the ssh command for the first `gerrit` instance the control does not come back to the above piece of code from the function `client_setup` and stalls there establishing the connection and waiting to capture any possible events. Thus, any other running `gerrit` instance's events are not captured.

Also, the `get_running_instances` function each time returns a different set of running `gerrit` instances. Thereby, I cannot create the processes all at once.

I also tried to use the `daemon` package to achieve the same. Below is the snippet of the code.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import daemon

class MyProcess(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, target, args):
        mp.Process.__init__(self, target=target, args=args)

while True:
    running = get_runnig_instances() #get all the running gerrit instances
    for instance in running:
        port_num = instance.port
        url = instance.ip
        with daemon.DaemonContext():
            proc = MyProcess(target=client_setup, args=(url,port_num,)) #client_setup(url,port_num) is a function that runs the command for the ssh connection to stream gerrit events
            proc.start()
            proc.join()
```

I faced the same problem here. How do I go about this? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and need help.

And sorry for the extensive explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think multiprocessing is designed primarily for spawning and communicating with other python interpreters in a pythonic way. You may need to use the lower-level subprocess module instead, with the Popen() method. You can help get rid of the annoying parallel stream buffer consumption by using a third party library like plumbum, or even Twisted. I have less knowledge of the Python 3 asyncio subprocess methodology under "Interprocess Communication and Networking" but that may make things easier too, if you are running Python 3.

Yet another other option is to try running an ssh client natively in python, for which paramiko is used. I don't think it has built-in async support for multiple connections so you may have to plumb that all yourself.

Comment: I will look into `asyncio`. It seems to fit my usecase. Thank you.

Comment: I have not used parallel-ssh but it seems quite active and makes valid arguments against its alternatives. Sounds like possibly the option with the least barrier to entry, provided you can install and use gevent with whatever python installation you're using. There is a thread stating that Parallel ssh does not yet support python 3 because gevent does not yet have broad support for it, although I don't see how they couldn't support it soon.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Will try with `parallel-ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

You're running:

```
proc.start()
proc.join()
```

The first one starts your new process. The second one waits for it to finish. Because you want to stream events, you want to leave that process running, not wait for it.

You can get rid of the main issue by just removing `proc.join()`. (or moving it to the cleanup code)

Comment: I tried a single `join` for all the processes. Yet the `gerrit` ssh connection is the blocking call and not letting any further execution.